# How to order photos correctly

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing a program in Excel which picks up all the photos from a directory and put them in the program. The main is that I need to put this photos separated and ordered because this archive will be printed and cutted.

What I tried is, to do an algorithm in VBA which tries to put this photos ordered 5 in the same row, 5 in next, 5 in next...

That looked easy, but I do not know why my program is giving me some problems.

It works and I have identified the failure. The problem is that when I have to change the row, the first photo of the next row inserts in the same place that the last photo of the last row. I mean that if I have 10 photos 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 it would be
1    2     3     4    5 (next line)
6    7    8     9     10

But what I get is:

1    2    3    4    56 (one code under the other one) (next line)
     7    8    9    10

That is surprising for me, because the space reserver for the first photo in next line stills empty but the photo is in the line before pasted with another one

That is my code which tries to order the images:

```
Count = 0
columna = 2
i = 0

cll = 1
Sheets("Hoja3").Select


For Each celda In rng


If Len(Trim(celda)) > 0 Then

        'defino la celda equivalente de la columna A y la selecciono
        If columna <= 10 Then
      '   MsgBox (columna)
        Set r1 = Cells(cll, columna)

        columna = columna + 2
        Else
        columna = 2
        cll = cll + 2
        Set rl = Cells(cll, columna)

        columna = columna + 2



        End If


        r1.Select


        'se inserta la imagen de la ruta definida


        Set Fotos = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Ruta & celda.Value)

        'con la posición definida respecto a la celda de la columna B seleccionada

        With Fotos

            .Top = r1.Top

            .Width = .Width / 2.5

            .Height = .Height / 2.5

            .Left = r1.Left + (r1.Width - Fotos.Width) / 3

            .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse

             r1.EntireRow.RowHeight = .Height

            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize

        End With

    r1.Select

End If

Next celda
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim pos As Long
pos = 0

For Each celda In Rng
    If Len(Trim(celda)) > 0 Then
    Set Fotos = Sheets("Hoja3").Pictures.Insert(Ruta & celda.Value)
    Set r1 = Sheets("Hoja3").Cells(((pos \ 5) + 1) * 2, (pos Mod 5) + 1 * 2)
        With Fotos
            .Top = r1.Top
            .Width = .Width / 2.5
            .Height = .Height / 2.5
            .Left = r1.Left + (r1.Width - Fotos.Width) / 3
            .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
            r1.EntireRow.RowHeight = .Height
       End With
    pos = pos + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Finally I solved this. The reference where I wanted to put the image was correct but I do not know why Excel did not do it. Writing test messages and changing the instruction finally I solved it. Thank you!